# Passing functions in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is my idea

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object pizD {

   def filePath = {
    new File(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("wikipedia/wikipedia.dat").toURI).getPath
  }

   def regex(line: String): pichA = {
    ......
    ......
    pichA(t1, t2)
  }
}

case class pichA(t1: String, t2: String)

object dushP {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

      val mirdd: RDD[pichA] = ???
```

How to integrate sc.textfile with my methods filePath and regex?I want to combine in order to get new rdd.

Comment: What you exactly want to do??/

Comment: @BalajiReddy Create rdd in one step,I want to escape sc.textfile and everything else.

Comment: something like tis ? sc.textfile(pizD.filepath) ?   just trying to understand

Comment: @BalajiReddy Yes,everything in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val baseRDD =sc.textfile(pizD.filepath).filter(line => {
         val value = pizD.regex(line) 
          if(value !=null)
             true
           else false
           })
```

Assuming `pizD.filepath` will give you file name as string and  `regex()` would return null value if regex din match. If the understanding is correct, then above code would do the trick.